# What is function $\sin$ without $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I'm solving a problem set in ODE:

[image]

This is the first time in my life that I see such functions $\sin,\cos,\tan$ without argument $x$.

I would like to ask if $\sin,\cos,\tan$ mean $\sin x,\cos x,\tan x$ or they mean something else.

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is bad notation but the only reasonable interpretation for, say 4), is $y$ is a function of $x$ and $y'(x)+y(x)\tan x =\sin x$.

Comment: $\sin$ is the sine function. $\sin(x)$ is the value of the sine function evaluated at $x$ (i.e. a real or complex number).

Comment: Thank you so much! It's a really bad notation :(

Comment: They should have been consequent and written 2) as $\cdot^3y'+4(1-\cdot^2)y=0$.

Comment: In a strict sense, 2) and 4) have no solution in this exercise, as their domain as ODE in $x$-direction is not $\Bbb R$, they are singular in some points, "solve in $\Bbb R$" can not be satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the convention is that if $f:X\to Y$ is a function, then $f(x)\in Y$ is the value at the point $x\in Y$. As you can do arithmetic with function values, you can do arithmetic with functions, applying the operation pointwise. Thus $h=f+g$ is $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for all $x$.

This gives a little complication if you want to write equations like 1) without too much decorations like writing $\forall x\in X$. One possible interpretation would then be that $x$ has a double meaning, it is the variable name and, where appropriate, a function itself, the identity function. So that 1) would be in this convention $xy'+y=2x$, avoiding the function evaluation notation.

In 3-5, the pendulum is moving to the extreme other side regarding the function evaluation notation in that $\sin$ etc. is used as function name in the same way as $f$ above. This is a very unusual notation, but not formally wrong. But it will look very strange in larger terms, $\sin+\cos$ is tolerable, but how to interpret $\sin\cos$?

Answer (score 2):

In this context you are dealing with functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

- $x$ stands for the identity function.
- $y$ stands for *some* function.
- $y'$ stands for the derivative of function $y$.
- $\sin$ stands for the function prescribed by $z\mapsto\sin(z)$ (same story for $\cos$ and $\tan$).

But I must say that there is some inconsistency which causes confusion.

- The author sometimes uses $y$ and another time $y(x)$.
- If $x$ is used as a function then IMV it is better to use another symbol (e.g. $z$) as argument of the function. Another way is not writing $x$ but writing $\mathsf{id}$ so that $x$ can be reserved as argument (as we are used to).

Answer (score 1):

A univariate function $f$ is usually defined by a domain, a codomain, and an analytic specification of how an input generates an output. The latter is given by specifying what $f(x)$ generates for any $x$ in the domain of $f$. Thus, $f$ is a function, but $f(x)$ is not: $f(x)$ is an output. Similarly, we may let $\sin$ denote the specific function that for any input $x$ in its domain, namely $\mathbb{R}$, generates the sinus of $x$, denoted as $\sin(x)$. Interpreted this way, the third equation you present can be read as: solve $y
'(x)\cos(x)-y(x)\sin(x)=-\cos(x)$ over $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score -4):

$\sin$ is an abbreviation for $\sin(x)$, in the same manner that $y'$ is an abbreviation for $y'(x)$ and $y$ for $y(x)$.

Comment: I disagree. $\sin$, $y$, $y'$ are functions. $\sin(x)$, $y(x)$, $y'(x)$ are the values of that function evaluated at $x$.

Comment: Your comment is confusing, as you claim to disagree with my answer yet you do not write anything that contradicts any part of my answer.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that *“$\sin$ is an abbreviation for $\sin(x)$”* because the former is a function, and the latter is not.

Comment: @pre-kidney A function is not the same as a function, evaluated at a given number. That is, $\sin(x)$ is a number. $\sin$ is not. It is not a simple case of abbreviation. Whenever $A$ is an abbreviation for $B$, we can always replace $A$ with $B$ in any statement and get an equivalent statement. In the case of $\sin$ and $\sin x$, this is not true, because $\sin(x)\in\mathbb R$ is a true statement, but $\sin\in\mathbb R$ is not.

Comment: It is absurd to disagree with a statement of the form "A is an abbreviation for B". It makes sense (and in this case is obvious) to disagree with a statement of the type @5xum is referring to, which again was *not* made in my answer. In fact, the common practice is to denote a function $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $x\mapsto \textrm{ExplicitExpression}(x)$ simply as ExplicitExpression$(x)$. There is no chance for confusion between the value of the function at the (unspecified) point $x$ and this notation, which (by the way) is the predominant notation used in ODE courses...

Comment: 'It is absurd to disagree with a statement of the form "A is an abbreviation for B"'... really? So is it absurd to disagree with the statement "EU is an abbreviation for Roman Empire"?